# Automatically Generate all words given root

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp

I am working on my research in the area of Natural Language Processing and for some result I have to automatically generate all words given the root of the word.
For example- User enter word -activate. The root word for this is- activ. 
The numbers of words that can be generated from root activ are -"activate,activated,activating
activates,activation,activator.

So I want a method to generate all this 6 words given the root activ.

Comment: We all want things, but things aren't free. What have you tried?

Comment: This is a rather difficult problem. You really need just a giant dictionary I would think. Also, asking a difficult problem whilst only writing a short paragraph, on a free website... you aren't going to get very good answers.

Comment: Hope you have understood the problem, and if not , then I can explain you giving more details.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to use a Trie: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

You would store your dictionary of words in the Trie, and then for any prefix (traversal of the tree up to a certain depth) you could search a little further down to obtain the words that exist with that prefix.

Comment: I was about to post this. It is definitely the right way to go. I wrote a pretty good one including fuzzy matching stuff in java here: https://github.com/ds300/norm/blob/master/src/norm/jvm/Trie.java

Comment: Using Dictionary mapping , I am basically restricting the user queries .See user has a right to query any thing like for same example , a user query - activate. I am able to generate the root for this word . What I need is the method that will automatically generate all the 6 words that can be formed from this root. And it is not possible to make dictionary of all words.

Comment: Like another query- disorder. The root of this word is -disord. The words that can be formed from this root are- disorder, disorders....etc... And how it is possible to make the dictionary of all the these words.

Comment: @user2540277 You might want to follow the link and read up on the answer, I don't think you quite understood what he meant.  Also, no one is going to give you a method, especially if you don't show us an attempt/what you have tried.  This is not a website that generates free code.